# Apply function on each row of a dataframe and increment a counter at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I know I can use `apply()` to apply a function on each row of a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Number' : [1,2,3]})
def func(row):
    pass
df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis =1 )
```

But I need to pass an incremental counter to `func()`. Something like below, but I don't know how to increment counter!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Number' : [1,2,3]})
def func(row, counter):
    pass
counter = 0 #initial value
df.apply(lambda x: func(x, counter), axis =1 )
```

Comment: There are functions like cumcount, cumsum, etc, that can help you do what you want (is not clear what you actually want)

Comment: In this situation I use global var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, [functions are first class citizens](https://realpython.com/lessons/functions-are-first-class-citizens-python/), even the ones that belong to objects, one way to achieve what you want is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Number': [1, 2, 3]})


class Counter:

    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.counter = seed

    def fun(self, n):
        if True:  # if you need to check a condition
            self.counter += 1  # add any value you see fit
        return n + self.counter


counter = Counter(0)

result = df["Number"].apply(counter.fun)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    2
1    4
2    6
Name: Number, dtype: int64
```

Note that first class citizenship means you do not need to create a lambda, you can pass the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use Global var

```
counter = 0 #initial value
def func(row):
    global counter
    counter+=1 
    pass

df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis =1 )
print(counter)
```