# global counter in recursive function applied to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, counter

Following inspiration from [Apply function on each row of a dataframe and increment a counter at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706103/apply-function-on-each-row-of-a-dataframe-and-increment-a-counter-at-the-same-ti) to apply recursive function with a termination counter to update a dictionary in a pandas dataframe and return the updated dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'dict': [{}, {}, {}]})

class DictModifier:

    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.counter = seed
        
    def update_dict(self, d: dict) -> dict:
#         global counter
        print(f"COUNTER:{self.counter}")
        
        keys=['a','b']
        values=[1, 2]
        for k,v in zip(keys,values):
            d.update({k:v})
        print(d)
        self.counter+=1
        if self.counter==3:
            return d
        return update_dict(d)

fun = DictModifier(0)

data['mod_dict'] = data["dict"].apply(fun.update_dict)
print(data)
```

Unfortunately this gives the error:

```
COUNTER:0
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
COUNTER:<__main__.Counter object at 0x7f2c78dd45e0>
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1062], in <module>
...

Input In [1062], in DictModifier.update_dict(self, d)
     21 if self.counter==3:
     22     return d
---> 23 return update_dict(d)

Input In [1037], in update_dict(d)
      7     d.update({k:v})
      8 print(d)
----> 9 counter+=1
     10 if counter==3:
     11     return d

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Counter' and 'int'
```

Expected results:

```
results = pd.DataFrame({'dict': [{}, {}, {}],'mod_dict': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]})
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a function `update_dict` in your global scope that uses a `Counter`?

Comment: not sure I understand, I guess I am not using global counter here (commented out), but without pandas and DictModifier class I used that to stop the recursion

Comment: You'll notice that the second error in the traceback is from `update_dict`, not `DictModifier.update_dict`. Basically you should be using `return self.update_dict(d)`, not `return update_dict(d)`. You have another issue beyond that with infinite recursion because the counter value gets to 4 (and so `self.counter==3` is never true after that), I don't really understand what your code is trying to do with the counter to tell you how to fix that.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the first point. For the second one, do you have a recommendation how  one would stop a recursion with or without a counter?

Comment: I don't really understand your code well enough to comment on that. Based on your desired result, it would seem a simple `return {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` is all you need. Presumably there is more to it than that though...